# Databases Relational algebra optimization

Tags: sql, relational-database, relational-algebra

I'm trying to do some query optimization; taking an SQL query into relational algebra and optimizing it.

My db tables schemas are as follow:

```
Hills(MId, Mname, Long, Lat, Height, Rating,... )
Runners(HId, HName, Age, Skill,... )
Runs(MId, CId, Date, Duration)
```

Where there may be many columns in Runners and Hills.

My SQL query is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Runners.HName, Runners.Age
FROM Hills, Runners, Runs
WHERE Runners.HId = Runs.HId AND Runs.MID = Hills.MId AND Height > 1200
```

So i could start by doing:

```
π Name, Age(σ Height > 1200 (Hills × Runners × Runs))
```

Or something like this and then optimizing it with a good choice of joins, but i'm not sure where to start

Comment: optimizing in what platform?  why not stick with the SQL and optimize that?  what is the end objective?

Comment: What exactly do you plan to achieve with such an optimization? Normally SQL queries are optimized for speed using the query plan and defining the correct indexes... what is the theory behind a relational algebra optimization?

Comment: Because that's what every RDBMS is doing in the back. Physical optimization is just the last part of it. Thanks to very "loose" way the relation model works, many queries can be written in many ways and order in which different relational operators are applied can mean massive difference in complexity. Ie. selections first vs. join first, etc.

Comment: @Randy. @littlegreen.  OP understands his problem better than you do.  You really need to read a few books **not the internet** before you post.

Comment: @PerformanceDBA: This is the second time today that I'm offended by your disrespectful know-it-all attitude. I respect your superior knowledge in some issues, but can you try to be more positive about it? We are all trying to help and learn here.

Comment: @littlegreen.  No disrespect intended. Read the FAQ.  This is not a learning site where amateurs post nonsense; it is site for people seeking answers from "professional programmers".  I am still waiting to find out how you can make a query perform faster by **adding** a `SELECT` and a `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @PDBA: Let's fight that one out in the other chat ;-) I'm pretty sure now that I got that one wrong, but in the process of discussing about it with you and djacobson I am learning. Afterwards, I will not make the same mistake again, and can teach others. That's the whole point of being here. It's not about giving the perfect answer and being torched otherwise. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq: **Be nice.** *Treat others with the same respect you'd want them to treat you. We're all here to learn together. Be tolerant of others who may not know everything you know. Bring your sense of humor.*

Comment: @littlegreen.  All good.  In addition, Have you heard of the concept of self-correction, and cleaning up ?  Why don't you delete your Answer. Fight. I don't fight, that's not the purpose of SO, my idea is, a professional does not get involved with personalities, yours or mine.  I am here just for the job.

Comment: What is the question? PS "Relational algebra optimization" doesn't mean anything specifiic enough for us to say what to do to do it. PS Anyway this is too broad. PS SQL optimization uses ideas from relational algebra optimization, but it is not limited to that. Neither are limited to relational algebra expression rewriting, ie relational algebra operators.

Answer (score 3):

You could start by using the SQL join notation:

```
SELECT DISTINCT P.HName, P.Age
  FROM Hills   AS H
  JOIN Runs    AS R ON H.MId = R.MId
  JOIN Runners AS P ON P.HId = R.HId
 WHERE H.Height > 1200
```

You can then observe that the WHERE condition applies only to Hills, so you could push down the search criterion:

```
SELECT DISTINCT P.HName, P.Age
  FROM (SELECT MId FROM Hills WHERE Height > 1200) AS H
  JOIN Runs    AS R ON H.MId = R.MId
  JOIN Runners AS P ON P.HId = R.HId
```

This is a standard optimization - and one which the SQL optimizer will do automatically.  In fact, it probably isn't worth doing much rewriting of the first query shown because the optimizer can deal with it.  The other optimization I see as possible is pushing the DISTINCT operation down a level:

```
SELECT P.HName, P.Age
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT R.HId
          FROM (SELECT MId FROM Hills WHERE Height > 1200) AS H
          JOIN Runs AS R ON H.MId = R.MId
       ) AS R1
  JOIN Runners AS P ON P.HId = R1.HId
```

This keeps the intermediate result set as small as possible: R1 contains a list of ID-values for the people who have run at least one 1200 metre (or is that 1200 feet?) hill, and can be joined 1:1 with the details in the Runners table.  It would be interesting to see whether an optimizer is able to deduce the push-down of the DISTINCT for itself.

Of course, in relational algebra, the DISTINCT operation is done 'automatically' - every result and intermediate result is always a relation with no duplicates.

---

Given the original 'relational algebra' notation:

- π Name, Age(σ Height > 1200 (Hills × Runners × Runs))

This corresponds to the first SQL statement above.

The second SQL statement then corresponds (more or less) to:

- π Name, Age ((π MId (σ Height > 1200 (Hills))) × Runners × Runs)

The third SQL statement then corresponds (more or less) to:

- π Name, Age ((π HId ((π MId (σ Height > 1200 (Hills))) × Runs)) × Runners)

Where I'm assuming that parentheses force the relational algebra to evaluate expressions in order.  I'm not sure that I've got the minimum possible number of parentheses in there, but the ones that are there don't leave much wriggle room for ambiguity.

Comment: I need to do this in relational algebra, not SQL